# Excel VBA; Updating a connection string

Tags: vba, excel, connection-string, excel-2010

I'm just trying to get VBA to update an OLEDB connection string. When I step through the code, I don't get any errors but the connection refresh fails and when I examine the connection string in the UI, it's obvious that my code has not changed it at all (hence the refresh failure). What have I missed?

Here is the code:

```
Sub UpdateQueryConnectionString(ConnectionString As String)

  With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection Name"). _
      OLEDBConnection
      .Connection = StringToArray(ConnectionString)
  End With
  ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection Name").Refresh
End Sub
```

The ConnectionString being fed in is:

```
ConnectionString = = "Provider=SLXOLEDB.1;Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE" _
& ";User ID=" & Username & ";Password=" & Password & _
";Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties=" _
& Chr(34) & "PORT=1706;LOG=ON;CASEINSENSITIVEFIND=ON;INCLUDECALCFIELDS=ON;" & Chr(34)
```

The function StringToArray is copied straight out of Example 4 on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105416

Comment: I suggest that you carefully check each of the properties in the locals window to make sure that they actually exist - I don't know the syntax by heart. Array(ConnectionString) seem like weird syntax, considering the fact that ConnectionString is a string.

Comment: @KimGysen seems to be right- what is this `array()` for, try without `array()`, just with `ConnectionString`.

Comment: I think the array part is generated by the Macro Recorder, and as @KimGysen says, doesn't apply here. Try it with just `ConnectionString`.

Comment: I tried it without the Array() but get a runtime error. A little digging found this [MS Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105416). See Example 4. The array is used to stop strings over 255 characters being truncated but I don't think I did this right. I'll update the code in my question to what I've done now. The UI still shows no changes to the Connection String (right or wrong).

Comment: I haven't counted the number of characters but your connection string doesn't look like it crosses 255 character limit?

Comment: `1` Also check the connection type of the connection `Connections("Connection Name")`. Is it `xlConnectionTypeODBC` or `xlConnectionTypeOLEDB` `2` Also check if the connection exists `3` Are you sure it is `ActiveWorkbook` and not `Thisworkbook`?

Comment: What does this give you `Msgbox ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection Name").Type` or `Msgbox ThisWorkbook.Connections("Connection Name").Type`

Comment: The Connection Type (according to UI) is an OLE DB Query and it does exist in the worksheet (it's the only one). If I use VBA to request the Type, the MsgBox returns the number 1. The string length isn't quite 255 but is close; a long username, password or extra setting could push it over. If I don't put the string into an Array, I get a runtime 1004 compilation error. If I use the StringToArray function suggested by MS, it doesn't error. If you record a macro to change the connection string in the UI, it places your string into an array.

Comment: Partial success. I've found that the following code will work and update the connection string but obviously it will do that for all connections in the workbook. How could I modify it to target just a single connection? `Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
    For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
            oledbCn.Connection = ConnectionString
    Next`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. The following code has worked.

```
Sub UpdateQueryConnectionString(ConnectionString As String)

  Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
  Dim oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
  Set cn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Connection Name")
  Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
  oledbCn.Connection = ConnectionString

End Sub
```

Just feed ConnectionString in as a string like I illustrated in my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

This line works for me to refresh code that uses OLEDB:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection Name").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
```

The reason seems to be that excel requires you to indicate the type even if you are referencing a specific, named, connection.

Comment: The refresh works but the UI is still reporting the connection string I entered through the UI. Not the connection string that the VBA should have inserted.

Comment: I checked the string, 238 characters, 258 with spaces...can you remove the CHR(34) [double-quote] - is that necessary?

Comment: yes, the CHR(34) is a required part of the connection string. It was the easiest way I found to escape the " as part of the string. No, I haven't tried getting a connection file.

Answer (score 0):

Even we can refresh particular connection and in turn it will refresh all the pivots linked to it.

For this code I have created slicer from table present in Excel:

```
Sub UpdateConnection()
    Dim ServerName As String
    Dim ServerNameRaw As String
    Dim CubeName As String
    Dim CubeNameRaw As String
    Dim ConnectionString As String

    ServerNameRaw = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ServerName").VisibleSlicerItemsList(1)
    ServerName = Replace(Split(ServerNameRaw, "[")(3), "]", "")

    CubeNameRaw = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_CubeName").VisibleSlicerItemsList(1)
    CubeName = Replace(Split(CubeNameRaw, "[")(3), "]", "")

    If CubeName = "All" Or ServerName = "All" Then
        MsgBox "Please Select One Cube and Server Name", vbOKOnly, "Slicer Info"
    Else
        ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(ServerName, CubeName)
        UpdateAllQueryTableConnections ConnectionString, CubeName
    End If
End Sub

Function GetConnectionString(ServerName As String, CubeName As String)
    Dim result As String
    result = "OLEDB;Provider=MSOLAP.5;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=" & CubeName & ";Data Source=" & ServerName & ";MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Update Isolation Level=2"
    '"OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=" & CubeName & ";Data Source=" & ServerName & ";Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"
    GetConnectionString = result
End Function

Sub UpdateAllQueryTableConnections(ConnectionString As String, CubeName As String)
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
    Dim Count As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim DBName As String
    DBName = "Initial Catalog=" + CubeName

    Count = 0
    For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        If cn.Name = "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then
            Exit For
        End If

        oTmp = Split(cn.OLEDBConnection.Connection, ";")
        For i = 0 To UBound(oTmp) - 1
            If InStr(1, oTmp(i), DBName, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
                oledbCn.SavePassword = True
                oledbCn.Connection = ConnectionString
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If Count = 0 Then
         MsgBox "Nothing to update", vbOKOnly, "Update Connection"
    ElseIf Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Connection Updated Successfully", vbOKOnly, "Update Connection"
    End If
End Sub
```