# Excel connection string DBQ & DefualtDir from Cell

Tags: excel

I have a connection string:

```
DSN=Excel Files;
DBQ=C:\Users\matt\Desktop\myfile.xlsm;
DefaultDir=C:\Users\matt\Desktop;
DriverId=1046;
MaxBufferSize=2048;
PageTimeout=5;
ReadOnly=0;
```

However I want this to pick up different users paths if the file is on their machine.

I have tried the following but I am getting the error:

> Cannot update. Database or object is read-only

Attempted Code:

```
DSN=Excel Files;
DBQ=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("J1").Value;
DefaultDir=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("J2").Value;
DriverId=1046;
MaxBufferSize=2048;
PageTimeout=5;
ReadOnly=0;
```

J1:

```
C:\Users\matt\Desktop\myfile.xlsm
```

J2:

```
C:\Users\matt\Desktop
```

Comment: Just an idea - change `.Value` to `.Value2` in the attempted code. You never know.

Comment: Btw, does it work, when you try it hardcoded with the connection string?

Comment: @Vityata change both or just one of them?

Comment: Yes the top one works when i specify dir and file name

Comment: Try with both of them. And if it does not work, write `MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("J1")` somewhere in the code. It should give you the correct input in the cells. If not, most probably you are referring to a wrong Worksheet.

Comment: @Vityata No tried both and one of each.

Comment: Have you tried with the MsgBox?

Comment: @Vityata What is the code for that

Comment: Now the **real** question - where do you put the connection string?

Comment: @Vityata Data > Connections

Comment: I guess it will not work, because of security issues. But you can totally do what you want to do, if you use a bit VBA and you make the connection there - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=connection+sql+from+cell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823865/dynamic-data-connection-string-without-vba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic data connection string without VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823865/dynamic-data-connection-string-without-vba)

Comment: @Vityata The answer on that question isn't exactly an answer